# Scatter Graph with four Quadrant for data analysis

Tags: excel, excel-2010, scatter-plot

I want to create a scatter (four quadrant) chart using Excel 2010.

what i am trying to achieve is

1. Graph will be divided in four region (high/high,High/Low, Low/High , Low/Low ) -xy axis
2. I want X and Y axis's min and max value as High and Low
3. each region will list the total no of item falling in each category

below is the sample data:

[image]

and this is the image of what i am trying to achieve as an end result (similar to this)

[image]

I want to have only four region

1. High/High
2. High/Low
3. Low/Low
4. Low/High

and each region will have total no of item falling in each category
i.e.

1. High/High - 2
2. High/Low - 2
3. Low/Low - 1
4. Low/High -6

can any one help me with how can i achieve the same using excel 2010

this is the [link](https://superuser.com/questions/485883/how-to-create-dynamic-scatter-plot-matrix-with-labels-and-categories-on-both-axi) i have used to achieve the expected end result

Comment: `this is the image of what i am trying to achieve` I don't understand why the link you provided is not enough? What is not in that link that you want to know?

Comment: i am not able to change the axis range ----
i am able to set range on x and y as -1 -0.5 0 0.5 1 ...etc.. but not able to change axis range to Low 0 High ..i suppose that he is using  x lable and y lable tables for custom axis range but i am not able to implement it in my graph..

Comment: @gpalex : thank you ser, you have made me read that post once more...yep my interpretation of those steps was wrong...All i needed to do was to make excessive use of Chart labeler add in...and plot the proper value of either X axe or Y Axe or at proper place in XY region. Plus lots of Chart formatting !

Comment: This question inspired a new tutorial on my blog last week: [Simple XY Quad Chart Using Axes as Quadrant Boundaries](http://peltiertech.com/simple-xy-quad-chart-axes-as-boundaries/). I didn't add the text labels to the axes, instead kept the numeric axis labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to say that i have found the solution to my question and i am posting it here in case someone wants to formulate somthing similar to this.

- For dividing Graph into four region..

  - i have set my graph axis min and max values to 0 and 1 respectively.
  - and for High and Low effect i have changed Low to -1 and high to 1 to divide it in four qudrant
- For custom naming of the axis (low and high ) instead or -1 and 1 on x and y axis

  - Created two more helper data table for X and Y axe and ploted the values directly on X and Y axis respectively
  - Now use XYLabler Addin or any other adding to add lable to your range and for my case it was Low and High respectively for X and y Axis.
- For Values at the center of each qudrant .
  create one more helper data table and X and Y axis should be center value of each qudrant for my case it is **(0.5,0.5) (0.5,-0.5),(-0.5,0.5),(0.5,-0.5)**

and for some formating to your plain chart , Use this tutorial by Jon Peltier [here](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/excel-chart-with-colored-quadrant-background/#comment-303341) to add color code to your region.

**TL;DR  :**

All you will need is :

1. moderate knowledge of excel Graph and potential for loads of formating
2. Labler Add-in for excel
3. and this two tutorial :[here](https://superuser.com/a/485901/237650) - answer by Dav on supeuser and [here](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/excel-chart-with-colored-quadrant-background/) tutorial by Jon Peltier  on peltiertech.com